# CakePHP - find username by id after $this->Model->find()?

Tags: cakephp

After doing $this->Event->find() I get the following result:

```
array(
'Event' => array(
    'event_id' => '72',
    'user_id' => '54c7e9f9-2520-48ca-ab70-1dfccf31a6d6',
    'title' => 'dfg',
    'start' => '2015-02-11 20:28:00',
    'public' => '0'
),
'User' => array(
    'password' => '*****',
    'id' => '54c7e9f9-2520-48ca-ab70-1dfccf31a6d6',
    'username' => '*',
    'slug' => '',
    'password_token' => null,
    'email' => '*',
    'email_verified' => true,
    'email_token' => '*',
    'email_token_expires' => '2015-01-28 20:41:45',
    'tos' => true,
    'active' => true,
    'last_login' => '2015-02-11 23:17:48',
    'last_action' => null,
    'is_admin' => true,
    'role' => 'registered',
    'created' => '2015-01-27 20:41:45',
    'modified' => '2015-02-11 23:17:48'
),
'EventGuest' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '84',
        'event_id' => '72',
        'guest_id' => '54db93be-0ef8-47d2-9bdb-118ccf31a6d6',
        'accepted' => '1'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '85',
        'event_id' => '72',
        'guest_id' => '54d1185f-8968-485e-b88f-1dd8cf31a6d6',
        'accepted' => '0'
    )
)
```

)

How can I resolve the guest_id to the username, located in the table users?

Basically I want something like the following output:
...

```
'EventGuest' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '84',
        'event_id' => '72',
        'guest_id' => '54db93be-0ef8-47d2-9bdb-118ccf31a6d6',
        'username' => 'Test',
        'accepted' => '1'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '85',
        'event' => '72',
        'guest_id' => '54d1185f-8968-485e-b88f-1dd8cf31a6d6',
        'username' => 'Test2',
        'accepted' => '0'
    )
)
```

)

(Notice the field **username**)

How can I achieve this without looking up every single username one by one, or is there a nice CakePHP-feature included?

**Relations:**

**Event:**

*belongsTo:*

- User

*hasMany:*

- EventGuest

**EventGuest:**

*belongsTo:*

- Event
- User

**User**

*hasMany:*

- Event
- EventGuest

Could you please explain me, how I can solve this issue efficiently?

With kind regards,

Battlestr1k3

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the name into the username field, that's simply not how Cake formats the results. You can do this:

Assuming you're using the containable behavior try this:

```
'contain' => [
    'User',
    'EventGuest' => [
        'User' => [
            'fields' => [
                'User.username'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

It should give you something like:

```
'EventGuest' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '84',
        'event_id' => '72',
        'guest_id' => '54db93be-0ef8-47d2-9bdb-118ccf31a6d6',
        'accepted' => '1',
        'User' => array(
            'username' => 'Test'
        )
    ),
)
```

If you urgently rely on having the "username" key in the array then run over the array in the Model::afterFind() callback and set the key and copy the name from the User array. But I wouldn't do it, waste of processing time.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't bring the desired result, there now is no EventGuest in the result. In Event.php i added public $actsAs = array('Containable');, aswell as in User.php and EventGuest.php.

Comment: For the User Model I am using a Plugin Located unter /Plugin/Users, maybe this could be important for the relationships

Answer (score 0):

Following Cakephp [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) the EventGuest table must be called EventUser.
Then, what is the relation from User to Event? We only know the relation from Event to User..
Then if I understand correctly your models you can find events of a specified user id with:

```
$this->User->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('User.username'=>$id)));
```

where $id is the id of the username you need to find.

Comment: Thanks, I already have array('conditions' => array('Event.' . $this->Event->primaryKey => $id)) to get just the event i am currently viewing, it doesn't affect which fields are in the result. I updated the relations (please see first post).

Comment: I cannot rename User to EventUser because i want to keep it general, a user doesn't only has events, he also has friendships etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by setting
    $this->Event->recursive = 3;
but I think I could do it more efficiently, because it shows even data from the Guest's friendships.

Edit: with the following line the output looks good:
    $this->Gamesession->contain(array('GamesessionGuest.User.username'));